# Load iframe after click or when appear

Tags: javascript, iframe, deferred

I need to optimize my website to PageSpeedInsight and I would like load an iframe only after click or when appear on the screen.

I have test many scripts but MapsAPI is always load when I test with Google PageSpeedInsight and the score is bad. Also, I can't update the iframe code.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+defer+mapsapi+after+click+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To only load an iframe when it appears on screen use `loading="lazy"`.

```html
<iframe src="https://example.com" loading="lazy"></iframe>
```

There's [an article on web.dev](https://web.dev/iframe-lazy-loading/) with more detail.